# Inheritance of abstract class by another abstract and non abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Is there any difference when an abstract class is extended by another abstract class and a non-abstract class ? For e.g., the parent abstract class has both abstract and non abstract methods.Is there any difference while implementing the methods when the abstract class is extended by an abstract class and a non abstract class , separately ?

Comment: `difference`  in which aspect ?

Comment: This question going to be closed as not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Have you tried it? If you try then you will come to know the difference.

Comment: For e.g., the parent abstract class has both abstract and non abstract methods.Is there any difference while implementing the methods when the abstract class is extended by an abstract class and a non abstract class , seperately ?

Comment: Go through this...http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to cover few basic points through the code. See the comments above the methods.

```
package abstractpkg;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();    // Compile-time error. C is abstract
        B b = new B();    // OK: B is concrete 
    }
}

abstract class A{
    abstract void methA();
    public void methB(){

    }
}

/**
 * Non-abstract class extending asbtract class.
 * */
class B extends A{
    /*
     * Since it is Non-abstract class, it must provide impl of abstract method because without impl of 
     * method Object of class can't be created.
     * */
    void methA() {

    };

    /*
     * This overriding is optional, since it's impl is already existing in super class.
     * If class B has to give spl impl then B should override this method
     * */
    @Override
    public void methB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.methB();
    }
}


abstract class C extends A{
    /*
     * Since C is also abstract it may or may not override the method. 
     * */

    /*
     * Overriding and providing impl is optional.
     * */
    @Override
    void methA() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if an  abstract class is extended by another abstract class then it no need to implement all parent class methods but the first concrete class which extends the abstract sub class must implement all the parent abstract classes methods.

Non abstract class must implement the parent abstract class methods